# How can I find the depth of a portion of the Valles Marineris?

Tags: mars, topographic-map

How can I find the depth of the low lying part of this image of the western part of Valles Marineris?[image]

I'm interested in the area northeast of Noctis Labyrinthus, southwest of Tithonium Chasma, north of Oudemans, and west of Ius Chasma.

I couldn't find any contour maps of Valles Marineris or Noctis Labyrinthus

Comment: Is this your own work or is it possible to cite and/or credit a source?

Comment: A search led me to this image which is on a Pinterest page, https://www.pinterest.com/pin/343892121520269817/?d=t&mt=login#.  The only source for the image was sciences.univ-nantes.fr, a French university.  I didn't know how to navigate a site written in French to find the particular page with this image.

Comment: btw I've just asked [Should questions about specific geographic features on rocky planets in our solar system be on-topic here?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/567/7982) please feel free to leave a comment or answer! Since you are active on both sites, you may have had a specific reason for posting here instead of there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find MOLA laser altimeter data here:https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/mgs/megdr.html.  The files are simple rectangular grids of differences between Martian "sea-level" and measure height at 1/128 degree resolution.  If you have the latitude and longitude, it is quite straightforward to find the height.

To view these files, you probably need the software found here: https://pds.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/about/pds3-tools/nasa-view.shtml

Looks like the software might be a little out-of-date, but you can give it a try.

Comment: If you mean the MEGDR Tiled Image Files, my MAC won't let me open those files.  I will have to look for another computer

Comment: @Bob516 - I updated the answer to point to the standard software tools for working with this data.  At one time I had my own tools, so my answer made it sound simpler than it really is...